# Researchers' names in titles of papers

Tags: publications, mathematics

I wonder if Mathematics is the field that has the highest ratio of researchers' names in the title of papers?

In the mailing I received from the arXiv this morning there are 14 papers that cite
earlier mathematicians:

---

- Title: A Green's function proof of the Positive Mass Theorem
- Title: Busemann functions in asymptotically harmonic Finsler manifolds
- Title: Inverse Gauss curvature flow in a time cone of Lorentz-Minkowski space
- Title: A survey of the Thurston norm
- Title: A proof of Kosniowski conjecture
- Title: Band width and the Rosenberg index
- Title: The Nirenberg problem on half spheres: A bubbling off analysis
- Title: The Ambrose-Singer Theorem for general homogeneous manifolds with
- Title: Uniformization of branched surfaces and Higgs bundles
- Title: Linear bounds for constants in Gromov's systolic inequality and related
- Title: An Invitation to Tropical Alexandrov Curvature
- Title: Approximating spaces of Nagata dimension zero by weighted trees
- Title: The Dirichlet-to-Neumann map, the boundary Laplacian, and H""ormander's
- Title: Benjamini-Schramm convergence of periodic orbits

---

And 12 titles that do not mention a name:

---

- Title: Combinatorial $k$-systoles on a punctured tori and a pairs of pants
- Title: Piecewise circular curves and positivity
- Title: Volume bounds for the canonical lift complement of a random geodesic
- Title: Uniform hyperbolicity of nonseparating curve graphs of
- Title: Zero-sum cycles in flexible non-triangular polyhedra
- Title: Distributional solutions to mean curvature flow
- Title: On certain irreducible finite group actions on surfaces
- Title: Counting essential minimal surfaces in closed negatively
- Title: Pullback coherent and squeezed states and quantization
- Title: Distance one surgeries on the lens space $L(n,1)$
- Title: Slope norm and an algorithm to compute the crosscap number
- Title: Comments on the cosmic convergence of nonexpansive maps

---

Of course this is hardly a random sample, depends on the day and the fields I follow.
But I wouldn't be surprised if Mathematics stands out in this regard.
I would be interested in any less-anecdotal data.
And speculation on: If true, why?

Comment: Is much speculation really required? Math tends to name theorems, postulates, etc after the people who published them and there really isn't another logical way of doing it.

Comment: @BryanKrause I think your word choice "published" is astute. As per the Arnold principle, "If a notion bears a personal name, then this name is not the name of the discoverer.". And according to the Berry principle, "The Arnold Principle is applicable to itself.".

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Do you want to know IF mathematics has the highest number of names in titles, WHY mathematics has the highest number of names in titles, or are you just surprised and is this not really a question? I understand your curiosity but I am voting to close this question because it is either a very specific research question or not a question at all IMHO.

Comment: You could answer this, of course with a comprehensive literature search over all fields and all of history. But what would the answer give you? And the answer today might be invalid tomorrow. Is there an "action item" here?

Comment: While this is an interesting question in its own right, it is not on-topic on a forum dedicated to the topic of Academia at large. Please see [our FAQ](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more details.

Comment: Math is arguably the field that deals with the most abstract kind of subject matter. Mathematical objects often have no immediate counterpart in the real (experienced) physical world, hence their names cannot be derived from such objects, and one uses the researchers'names instead.

Comment: @lighthousekeeper: Yes. But interestingly, the same is not true in theoretical computer science, which is equally abstract. Maybe because of the shorter history of publications in CompSci. But also some cultural difference, I think.